# How do you delete everything after the second instance of a word in a cell/delete duplicate in a string?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My data in one column looks like this:

```
101 Hello 2, New York, NY 10002101 Hello 2, New York, NY 10002
```

Basically, the same string is repeated into the cell twice.

How do I delete the second instance of the same string in the cell (or how do I delete everything after the second instance of the first number in the string -- I tried to make a column extracting the first number of the string, so a column that has just "101", and I'm trying to reference it to delete everything after the second time it appears in the first string, if that makes sense)?

I'm trying to convert

`101 Hello 2, New York, NY 10002101 Hello 2, New York, NY 10002`

to:

```
101 Hello 2, New York, NY 10002
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your text is really just the same thing repeated twice you can use something like:

```
=LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)/2)
```